# Form with required field. Deleting the new record

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form that is bounded to a table and I have one required field in the table. When I try to enter a new record through the form, and then I decide not to enter the record, I get stuck, It keeps saying that I need to enter a value for the required field. Is there a way for the form to have a submit button, and only when I click this button, the record goes into the table and otherwise it just gives me an interface through the form where I can edit the values without worrying about the required fields. Any help is appreciated!
Any other approach is welcome too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you add data to a record Access creates the record (and assigns it an ID#).  In the BEFORE UPDATE event for the control for the required field, check to see if the value is null, and if so, UNDO the changes.  Example:

```
Private Sub txtControlName_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
  If IsNull(Me!txtControlName) Then
    Me.Undo
  End If
```